# JSON com campos variáveis

Tags: json

Eu recebo de um PHP que acessa o banco MySQL um JSON que nem sempre tem os mesmos campos, ora vem assim:

```
[{"clu_nome":"Sport Club Corinthians Paulista","clu_estado":"SP","clu_ordem":5,"pon_pontos":"1858","pon_jogos":"1298","pon_vitori":"557","pon_empate":"383","pon_derrot":"358","pon_golpro":"1727","pon_golcon":"1364","pon_saldo":"363","pon_aprove":"54"},{"clu_nome":"Sport Club Internacional","clu_estado":"RS","clu_ordem":9,"pon_pontos":"1847","pon_jogos":"1290","pon_vitori":"559","pon_empate":"356","pon_derrot":"375","pon_golpro":"1743","pon_golcon":"1334","pon_saldo":"409","pon_aprove":"54"}]
```

ora assim, podendo ter outros formatos:

```
[{"clu_nome":"S\u00e3o Paulo Futebol Clube","clu_estado":"SP","clu_ordem":3,"pon_classi":"224"},{"clu_nome":"Sport Club Corinthians Paulista","clu_estado":"SP","clu_ordem":5,"pon_classi":"202"},{"clu_nome":"Gr\u00eamio Foot-Ball Porto Alegrense","clu_estado":"RS","clu_ordem":10,"pon_classi":"185"},{"clu_nome":"Sport Club Internacional","clu_estado":"RS","clu_ordem":9,"pon_classi":"185"},{"clu_nome":"Clube Atl\u00e9tico Mineiro","clu_estado":"MG","clu_ordem":1,"pon_classi":"182"}]
```

Como eu faço para selecionar cada campo para montar numa ListView?

Nenhum exemplo que vejo por aí ajuda a fazer isto.

Comment: Nao entendi bem sua duvida, mas voce pode iterar no item como se fosse um array php normal se converter o JSON.  `$arr = json_decode($json_banco);`

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de dizer que recebo o JSON num aplicativo no Android Studio, é nele que preciso manipular os dados. Se alguém tiver um exemplo prático eu vou agradecer muito

Comment: Seria isso? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object

Comment: Esta resposta também é em PHP, não Android Studio. Os exemplos que vejo sabem que tipo de campo vem, mas tem campo que ora vem e ora não vem. Nos exemplos, sempre term "clu_nome", mas "pon_pontos" pode ir e pode não vir, dependendo da query

Comment: Essa resposta é java

Comment: Não sou expert em Java, uso o básico no Android Studio, não entendi, mas vou avaliar com mais calma

Comment: O que eu preciso é pegar o nome de cada coluna e seu conteúdo para composição de uma ListView, mas não posso referenciar as colunas pelo nome porque não sei se os possíveis nomes existirão mesmo no JSON. Talvez isso ajude vocês a me ajudarem. Já fiz todo tipo de pesquisa e não consegui isto

Comment: Monta as colunas em um foreach pegando as chaves no array. Assim, independente de como venha, vai funcionar. O que acha?

Comment: Resolvido:

            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < jsonChildNode.length(); j++)
                {
                    labels.add(jsonChildNode.names().getString(j));
                    labels.add(jsonChildNode.getString(jsonChildNode.names().getString(j)));
                }
            }